# Debug Visual Studio Publish to Azure - Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, azure

I have Django app that I need to test publish on Azure websites. I try the Publish on visual studio but it fails with no log output

I am using the Web Deploy publish feature. https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Django-and-MySQL-on-Azure

```
------ Build started: Project: ota, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
------ Publish started: Project: ota, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

pretty useless, right?

I should mention I imported the project later as python project and VS recognized it, and I created virtual env with all necessary python libs and I can debug the project on localhost. But publishing to Azure is failing and I can't debug because there is no useful trace

Answer (score 0):

There are not any more information shown Azure WebApp for Django had been created first. I suggest that you can try to follow the offical tutorial [`Creating web apps with Django in Azure`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/) to check your every steps.

Note the key steps below first.

> **Web App Creation on Portal**
>   The first step in creating your app is to create the web app via the Azure Portal.
>
> 1. Log into the Azure Portal and click the **NEW** button in the bottom left corner.
> 2. In the search box, type "python".
> 3. In the search results, select **Django (published by PTVS)**, then click **Create**.
> 4. Configure the new Django app, such as creating a new App Service plan and a new resource group for it. Then, click **Create**.

It seems like as below.

[image]

Then, you can follow the wiki https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Django-and-MySQL-on-Azure#publish-to-an-azure-website to publish to Azure in VS, and follow the wiki page https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Azure-Remote-Debugging to enable remote debugging for Django with Python in VS.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I had already went with another solution - Bitnami Django on Azure. The tutorial you mentioned doesn't show how to port an existing project and has same material (applicable to my situation) to the other ones I was looking at as well. Why doesn't visual studio show the error to debug further?  Bitnami was very simple to bring up (Compute - solution ) and documentation is FAQ based so I can find situations applicable to me. I wish I could've gotten VS publish to simply work but there were no errors for me to debug... hopeless case.

Comment: @SaherAhwal, Using VS is not only way for publishing a Django App on Azure. You can try to use FTP or Git or other ways like shown in the [page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/). Meanwhile, you need to focus the configuration in the `web.config` file to make sure IIS on Azure can help launching  the python instance for Django. Please refer to the [vedio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/multi-language-azure-web-sites-with-php-node-and-dotnet/).